# Autoloading in Codeigniter Custom Libraries

Tags: codeigniter

When autoloading libraries, helpers or models, does this also hold true when making custom libraries? I'm asking since loading CI items in custom libraries always start with

```
$this->ci =& get_instance();
```

Since you have to access the CI super object before you can load anything, does this mean that autoloading will not apply and so I'll have to load each item one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: previous answer didn't focus what has been asked.]

You want to know if autoloaded libraries are available in custom libraries. The answer is **yes**, but you will still need the super object to access them.

Having to access the CI super object, does not mean that autoloading will not apply, at all! The already autoloaded libraries, helpers and models will be there, loaded and available.